# Got a CS0165 Error, everything I searched doesn't help me

Tags: c#

```
int numRangeFloor;
        switch (hardness)
        {
            case 1:
                numRangeFloor = 5;
                break;
            case 2:
                numRangeFloor = 10;
                break;
            case 3:
                numRangeFloor = 100;
                break;
        }
        Random difficulty = new Random();
        difficulty.Next(0, **numRangeFloor**);
```

**Edit:**  For those that haven't memorized all the codes:

[CS0165](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0165) is "Use of unassigned local variable 'name'"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0165

Comment: Why not? What don't you understand? What do you expect to happen if `hardness` is `73`?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `numRangeFloor` is not assigned in every case. To the compiler, it's unclear what `numRangeFloor` is supposed to be if `hardness` is anything but 1, 2 or 3.

The solution is to either initialize `numRangeFloor` with a default value or add a `default:` statement to the switch case.

Here is an example:

```
int numRangeFloor;
        switch (hardness)
        {
            case 1:
                numRangeFloor = 5;
                break;
            case 2:
                numRangeFloor = 10;
                break;
            case 3:
                numRangeFloor = 100;
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception();
        }
        Random difficulty = new Random();
        difficulty.Next(0, **numRangeFloor**);
```